# How to get colorfull material design icons to use in android app

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons in my layout such as facebook,twitter,google-maps, and call. I want to use colorful material design icons for them. so from where can i get the material design icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get nice social networking icons here:

[Source1](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/free-social-media-icons/)

[Source2](https://blog.bufferapp.com/social-media-icons)

[Source3](http://designscrazed.org/free-social-media-icons/)

[image: Sample Icons]

Answer (score 1):

use this web [site](https://www.webresourcesfree.com/best-free-android-ui-kit-psd/).

a complete list of  Android UI Kit PSD which you can use for free in your designs.